# Convert const char* into a char*

Tags: c++, char

I'm always wondering about the complaint of the compiler when I declare and define a char*-variable.

```
char* myChar = "Char";
```

The compiler will complain that it cannot convert const char* to char*. It need an explicit conversion like

```
char* myChar = (char*)"Char";
```

My first question is if this is the correct way to initialize a char* with a const char*. And my second question is, why the compiler need this explicit conversion. I think there is no great difference between const char* and char* except the const.

Comment: `const` *is* the great difference. Pointer to some non-const qualified type and pointer to const-qualified type are different, unrelated types.

Comment: There is no "correct" way to initialize a `char*` with a `const char*`. one is a pointer to mutable data, the other a pointer to immutable data. You can implicitly convert the former to the latter; you're playing with fire forcing conversion to the former from the latter, *especially* if you "think there is no great difference between const char* and char*".

Comment: Try this: `char* myChar = (char*)"Char"; myChar[0] = 'x';` kaboom!

Comment: @rustryx Nice Example. I assume that memcpy can avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

On a technical level, there is a great difference between `const MyType*` and `MyType*` and it is easier to see in your example `char* myChar = "Char";` in that the litteral string can be part of memory that may not be changed, but by assigning that to a non-const pointer, you say that you may well planning to change some characters anyway. That behavior is undefined. It may work and it may make your program stop unexpectedly and you can't even rule out any other behavior.

By casting (prefer `const_cast` in C++), you are saying to the compiler that you know what you're doing and you know better. The normal solution is `const char* myChar = "Char";` or even `const char* const myChar = "Char";` if you're not planning to point to other char arrays.

In C++, I find it even clearer working with `std::string` if you want to work with strings.

Comment: Now I understand. My literal "Char" is placed in the EXE's .data-section which is fixed. const char* ... is poining to this .data-section address, or?

Comment: Yes. By the way, the compiler is allowed to put the litteral string in non-const data and to reuse multiple uses of it, so in that case, if you overwrite one, all the others would give the new value even when declared in a later used function. That is also possible undefined behavior. Most commonly, it is in a data-section where an update will cause the program to stop.

Answer (score 0):

To the advanced programmer, there is definitely a great difference between const and non-const, in terms of integrity, security, and performance.
We basically use const when we want to emphasize that a particular object/function/variable isn't allowed to be changed by the user.

check [const correctness](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html)

The best-practice way to add/remove const/volatile modifiers is by using const_cast operator.

check [The const_case operator](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=expressions-const-cast-operator-c-only)